# AFNetworking & CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, afnetworking

I am trying to show a collection view that has a custom collection view cell. My array seems to be empty and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code. I have tried everything!

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"opportunityCell";
    OpportunityCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Opportunity *opportunity = [self.opportunitiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    for (Opportunity *opportunity in self.opportunitiesArray) {
        NSString *opportunityBanner = opportunity.imageBanner;
        NSURL *imageURl = [NSURL URLWithString:opportunityBanner];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURl];
        RKCardView *cardView = [[RKCardView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.cellView.bounds.size.width, cell.cellView.bounds.size.height)];

        cardView.coverImageView.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
        cardView.titleLabel.text = @"";
        cardView.profileImageView.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];

        UITextView *descriptionView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 180, cell.cellView.bounds.size.width - 15, cell.cellView.bounds.size.height / 3)];
        descriptionView.text = opportunity.opportunityName;
        descriptionView.editable = NO;
        descriptionView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:18];
        descriptionView.contentMode = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

        UITextView *timeView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 180 + cell.cellView.bounds.size.height, cell.cellView.bounds.size.width - 5, cell.cellView.bounds.size.height / 3)];
        timeView.text = opportunity.endDateTime;
        timeView.editable = NO;
        timeView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14];
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        [cardView addSubview:descriptionView];
        [cardView addSubview:timeView];
        [cell.cellView addSubview:cardView];
        [descriptionView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    return cell;

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    self.opportunitiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"opportunities/" parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         Opportunity * opportunity = [[Opportunity alloc]init];

         if (responseObject[@"opportunities"]) {
             [KVNProgress showSuccess];
             NSDictionary *dataDict = responseObject[@"data"];
             opportunity.opportunityID = dataDict[@"id"];
             opportunity.opportunityDescription = dataDict [@"description"];
             // opportunity.isDonatable = dataDict[@"donatable"];
             opportunity.endDateTime = dataDict[@"end_datetime"];
             opportunity.opportunityName = dataDict[@"name"];
             opportunity.opportunityType = dataDict[@"opp_type"];
             opportunity.organizationID = dataDict[@"organization_id"];
             //  opportunity.isPrivate = dataDict[@"donatable"];
             opportunity.startDateTime = dataDict[@"start_datetime"];
             //   opportunity.isAttendable = dataDict[@"attendable"];
             opportunity.imagecard = dataDict[@"image_card_organization"];
             opportunity.imageBanner = dataDict[@"image_banner"];

             [self.opportunitiesArray addObject:opportunity];

         }
         [self.collectionView reloadData];

         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

     }
         failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     }];
}
```

I am also using a framework called RKCardView to create my cell. Should I have just created a custom cell instead of using a third party framework?

Comment: can you show me the code where you're setting the collection view delegate and datasource to self? Or just confirm if you have set it in the storyboard or xib

Comment: Have you got this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Things you have to check

In your `ViewDidLoad`

1. data source `self.collectionView.datasource = self;`
2. delegate `self.collectionView.delegate = self;`
3. register your cell `[self.collectionView registerClass:[OpportunityCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"opportunityCell"];`

> sample code

```
(void)viewDidLoad  
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[OpportunityCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"opportunityCell"];
    //use registerClass: or registerNib:
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure `self.opportunitiesArray` has the data you want, it means you get the data from network

Second, make sure you have set your UICollectionView dataSource to a valid object, like

`self.collectionView.dataSource = self`

You need to implement the required protocols for `UICollectionViewDataSource`

You better make sure `[self.collectionView reloadData];` is executed on main queue, you are calling it in the block without main queue, there is a risk.

Better to use weakSelf in block, you are using self directly, this will cause `retain cycle` if you are not careful

Use like below:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

If you could use LLDB to debug your code, it will be very helpful to identify your problem. Usually, I have listed all possbiel reasons.

You could try add a breakpoint at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and checkout if you get valid opportunity object and sub views are added correctly

Comment: I just checked the count of my array.. and it is 0 for some reason. I don't understand how it could be 0 when I added it by doing this   [self.opportunitiesArray addObject:opportunity];

Comment: do you have `opportunity` get what you want before you add it into `self.opportunitiesArray`

Answer (score 0):

you can check your code,I usually addCollectionView use the code like :

```
- (void)addCollectionView {
    CGRect collectionViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, kControllerHeaderViewHeight+kControllerHeaderToCollectionViewMargin, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionViewFrame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    //    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, CYLFilterHeaderViewHeigt);  //设置head大小
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[FilterHeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:kHeaderViewCellIdentifier];
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0);
    self.collectionView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.bgScrollView addSubview:self.collectionView];
}
```

then add CollectionViewDataSource method like :

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return <#numberOfItemsInSection#>;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:<#reuseIdentifier#> forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell forItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell
   forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    <# statements #>
}
```